# DropDownList not getting populated from Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a quick question. I have a dropDownList that I'm trying to get populated with id's from a stored procedure. However it doesn't seem to work. this is my dropDownlist:

```
 <div id="newExpenseTypeDialog" style="display:none;">
        <label>Select new CaseFile:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFiles" DataSourceID="dsMyCaseFiles" DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="524px" />
</div>
```

And this is my DataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyCaseFiles" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="p_CaseFiles_ListActiveCaseFilesAssignedTo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="InvestigatorID" SessionField="InvestigatorID" />
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="AssignedTo" SessionField="InvestigatorID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My Stored procedure needs two parameter. InvestigatorID and AssignedTo. It will then find return all the FileID's that match.

Now this is my .aspx.cs side code :
(Page_load)

```
if (Request.QueryString["ExpenseID"] != null)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFiles";
            ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
            ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
        }
    }
```

and my Pre_Render:

```
protected void ddl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    try
    {
        if (ddl.Items[0].Value != "-1")
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
    }
    catch
    {
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
    }
}
```

The list has the pre_render working and what not, just no data from my stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

i think you just forget to call DataBind method

```
ddlCaseFiles.DataBind();
```

in `if(!ispostback)` block after that three line

Comment: I will try that and get back to you

Comment: Still doesn't seem to populate it. It only has the pre_render content

Comment: @user1084319 - have you chaed session variable passed in soruce proceudre having value or not..

Comment: @user1084319 - remoe prerender event and check its loading data or not...remove dll_PreRender event and check

Answer (score 1):

You haven't Binded your dropdown list yet

```
if (Request.QueryString["ExpenseID"] != null)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFiles";
        ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
        ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
        ddlCaseFiles.DataBind();  //You need to Bind it here
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you